# How to fetch Customer Payments from Netsuite using mulesoft connector

Tags: mule, netsuite, mule-studio, mulesoft, suitetalk

I want to search Netsuite customer payments using mulesoft Netsuite connector

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 urn:messages.platform.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns01 urn:sales.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns02 urn:common.platform.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns03 urn:core.platform.webservices.netsuite.com
ns ns04 urn:customers.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com
---
{
    ns0#search: {
        ns0#searchRecord @("xmlns:ns01": ns01, xsi#"type": "ns01:TransactionSearch"): {
            ns01#basic: {
                ns02#recordType @(operator: "is"): {
                    ns03#searchValue: attributes.queryParams.recType
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

recType is the parameter I am using to pass different record types. I am able to fetch "Invoice", "SalesOrder", "CreditMemo" etc but when I pass "CustomerPayment" I doesn't give me any data.

Though I understand CustomerPayment fall under `urn:customers.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com` namespace, even when I try to use this namespace I get "unexpected error with some random ID".

Any lead would be really helpful here.

Currently I am using connector version 11.5.8

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. The integration user did not have access to customer payments